# Why am I getting "no route matches [POST]" in my nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resources, routes

I have a project that contains `projects` that have `todos` that have `tasks`.  When I try to create a new task, I get this error when I submit:

```
No route matches [POST] "/projects/1/todos/19/tasks/new"
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for [@todo, @todo.tasks.new], :url => new_project_todo_task_path(@project, @todo) do |f| %>

        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :description, "Description" %><br />
          <%= f.text_area :description %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit %> or <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", :id => "cancel_new_task_link" %>
        </div>  

    <% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticated?
  before_filter :get_project_and_todo

  respond_to :html, :xml, :json, :js

  def new
    @task = @todo.tasks.new
  end

  def create
    @task = @todo.tasks.new(params[:task])
    if @task.save
      respond_with @todo, :location => project_todo_path(@project, @todo)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def get_project_and_todo
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @todo = @project.todos.find(params[:todo_id])
  end


end
```

Here are my routes:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :todos do
        resources :tasks
    end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL should not be `new_project_todo_task_path(@project, @todo)`. You don't need to specify the URL here as Rails will imply it from the parameters passed in to `form_for`.

If the final object is a new object and not persisted in the database then it will make a `POST` request to, in this case, `/projects/:project_id/todos`. You're declaring in your example that you want to make a `POST` request to `/projects/:project_id/todos/new`, for which there is no `POST` route and that is why it's failing.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  Here is what I used:    <%= form_for [@project, @todo, @todo.tasks.new] do |f| %>